# How to migrate m:n association table ids from integer to uuid in sequelize with postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have two models, book and author, with a many to many association. I originally implemented both of them to have auto-incrementing integer ids but now I want to switch both to UUID. I added the UUID datatype to the associations:

```
// models/book.js
const { Model } = require('sequelize')

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Book extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      Book.belongsToMany(models.Author, {
        as: 'authors',
        through: 'BookAuthors',
        foreignKey: {
          allowNull: false,
          name: 'bookId',
          type: DataTypes.UUID
        }
      })
    }
  }
  
  Book.init(
    {
      title: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      }
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'Book'
    }
  )
  return Book
}
```

```
// models/author.js
const { Model } = require('sequelize')

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Author extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      Author.belongsToMany(models.Book, {
        through: 'BookAuthors',
        foreignKey: {
          allowNull: false,
          name: 'authorId',
          type: DataTypes.UUID
        }
      })
    }
  }
  Author.init(
    {
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(75),
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
      },
      biography: DataTypes.TEXT
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'Author'
    }
  )

  return Author
}
```

And in the migrations to set up the database I changed both id attributes to:

```
id: {
  allowNull: false,
  defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
  primaryKey: true,
  type: Sequelize.UUID
}
```

I don't care about the data in the tables, I already dropped the table and recreated it with the new code, but starting the server then fails with the following error:

`Key columns "authorId" and "id" are of incompatible types: integer and uuid.`

while executing the statement:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "BookAuthors" ("createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "authorId" INTEGER NOT NULL  REFERENCES "Authors" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, "bookId" UUID NOT NULL  REFERENCES "Books" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, PRIMARY KEY ("authorId","bookId"));`

Afaik, the association table is automatically created by Sequelize while calling `db.sequelize.sync()`. So then why does it accept UUID for books, but not for authors?

Comment: Please show the whole model definitions and also I didn't get it either you use migrations or `sync` method (you mentioned both)

Comment: I have updated the model definitions. I want to use migrations to define and update my tables, but I have read that the way to create association tables with sequelize is to define the associations (via through) in the models and then call `sequelize.sync()`. What would you recommend?

Comment: For real production project I'd recommend to use migrations of course. If it's just simple dev/pet project then maybe it's enough to use `sync` for simplicity

Comment: Thank you very much! With your help I switched to migrations completely, and I added a migration for the association table as well. Declaring the PKs in the models was the missing part, now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't indicate PKs in models explicitly because now you want to define them with other than the default DB type (integer):

Book model:

```js
Book.init(
    {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.UUID
      },
      title: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      }
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'Book'
    }
  )
```

Author model:

```js
Author.init(
    {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.UUID
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(75),
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
      },
      biography: DataTypes.TEXT
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'Author'
    }
  )
```